# Design Database for Billing System

Tags: database, django, database-design, django-models

I am trying to design a django app that will help me to manage my litte shop. I would like to be able to make bills in an easier way than now but I need some help with the database design.

Right now I have it this way:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  price = models.IntegerField()

class Article(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
  qty = models.IntegerField()
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Order(models.Model):
  number = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
  client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
  invent = models.ForeignKey(Invent)
  articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
```

I doubt that Product-Article design is well done, there should be a different way to do this because I will have many repeated data in my DB.

Another question is if the article is "owned" by the order or if the article has an order to "belong", I don' know if the question is clear.

EDIT1:

My thought about Product-Article:

```
   +------------------+                   +----------------+       +------------------+
   |  Product         |                   |   Product      |       |     Article      |
   |------------------|                   |----------------|       |------------------|
   |                  |                   |                |       |                  |
   | Name             |                   |  Name          <--------+ Product         |
   |                  |           VS      |                |       |                  |
   | Price            |                   |                |       |                  |
   |                  |                   |  Price         |       |  Qty             |
   | Qty              |                   |                |       |                  |
   +------------------+                   +----------------+       +------------------+
```

And the other question is:

```
    +------------------+                               +-----------------+      +--------------+
    |     Order        |                               |   Order        <-------+   Article    |
    |------------------|                               |-----------------|      |--------------|
    | Number           |      +--------------+         |                 |      |              |
    |          +------------->|  Article     |         | Number          |      | ...          |
    | Client   | +----------> +--------------+    VS   |                 |      |              |
    |          | |     |                               | Client          |      + Order        |
    | ...      | |     |                               |                 |      |              |
    |          | |     |                               | ...             |      +--------------+
    | Articles + +     |                               |                 |
    +------------------+                               +-----------------+
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the statement *"I doubt that Product-Article design is well done, there should be a different way to do this because I will have many repeated data in my DB"?*

Comment: It's difficult to determine what you are asking here; try formulating your question in such a way that it can be expressed in 15 words or less *in the title of your question.*  Your question needs to be more specific.

Comment: I have added some draws where I try to explain it better.

Comment: Is this right? 
You've got a Product (in example a "Lindor candy") and an Article (which is a Product in different packaging). Client is buying Articles which is then saved in Order. If so, the price should be in Article object.

Comment: +1 just for the nice ascii art

Comment: Can you explain what the "article" and "product" classes actually do? It's common to have an article with different variants - t-shirts in small, medium, large, for instance. It's also common to hold historical price data, so you can bill someone the price of the article as it was when they place the order, not when you print the invoice. Neither option is reflected in your design...

Comment: My guess is that `Product` and `Order` (should) have a many-to-many relationship and that `Article` means a `ProductOrderingDetail` so the Product-Order association table should be modeled through that (`Article`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  current_price = models.IntegerField()

class Order(models.Model):
  number = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
  client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
  invent = models.ForeignKey(Invent)
  total = models.IntegerField()

class Article(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
  order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
  qty = models.IntegerField()
  price = models.IntegerField()
```

Check also this:  **[Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)**

Comment: Yes, I am trying to discuss which code is better, the one you have or mine.

Thanks